# After 12 requests (~60 sec) Firebase or Python-firebasin library do not send and receive data

Tags: python, firebase, account

I have a problem, please help me.

I created Python script what is collaborating with Firebase to save and receive data.
My script works with python-firebasin library ([link to python-firebasin](https://github.com/abeisgreat/python-firebasin)).
I tested my application one week with my Firebase account - HACKER PLAN. All works fine all this time.
After that i buy premium account with special URL like x.firebaseio.com here begins my problems.
I import json structure from my old firebase to my new firebase account and set in my Python script new firebase URL to my new firebase account.
So now all must works fine with my new firebase premium account.
I run my script and ~60 seconds my script works fine. Callback events work, set values works.
But after ~60 seconds Firebase do not receive and do not send any callback to my Python script.
For debugging i wrote simple script what send unixtime to firebase every 5 second. So all works fine first 12 requests (12 * 5 = ~60 sec), after what firebase do not receive any data.
Python do not send any error and callback too.
Atention: All works fine with my old Firebase account - HACKER PLAN!

```
from firebasin import Firebase
from time import sleep, time

# Firebase
vGFirebase = None

vGCompanyId = '1'
vGHardwareId = '0000000000123123'

i = 1

vGFirebase = Firebase('https://subdomain.firebaseio.com')

def errorCallback(data):
    print('errorCallback', data)

while True:
    try:
        pingChild = vGFirebase.child('data/app/pings/' + str(vGCompanyId) + '/' +  str(vGHardwareId))
        sendTime = int(time())
        pingChild.set(sendTime, errorCallback)
        print(i, 'send ', sendTime)
        i += 1
        sleep(5)
    except:
        print('Exception')
        break

vGFirebase.waitForInterrupt()
```

I enable Debug mode in python-firebasin library.
So after 12 requests i got this message:
**(('Closed down :(', 1006, 'Going away'),)**
So i think this is because Firebase close connection... But why?

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: As posted by Abe Haskins when this question was previously [asked on the mailing list](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/firebasin/1473f6a0a9060a39): Hmm, this is probably due to the bad quality "keep alive" packet which Firebasin sends to Firebase. I'll speak with some engineers and see if I can't get it resolved.

Comment: At the moment i change my firebase account and my script works now. But i still have many problems with firebasin (python library). I do not receive error message when firebasin set/update data when no internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firebasin does not start a Heartbeat to keep the connection alive.  You can easily start one yourself.  After the line creating `vGFirebase`:

```
from ws4py.websocket import Heartbeat
while not vGFirebase.connection.data:
    sleep(1)
Heartbeat(vGFirebase.connection.data,2).start()
```

Unfortunately, the _keep_alive method in dataref.py seems to not get along with hacker plans and causes them to disconnect when it fires its own keepalive message, so you'll also need to disable that.  You can do so on the fly by adding

```
import firebasin
firebasin.dataref.RootDataRef._keep_alive = lambda *x: None
```

to the top of your script.  A more permanent, but non-portable solution would be to patch dataref.py to replace it's _keep_alive method with one that starts ws4py's Heartbeat.  I've submitted a pull request to do that upstream; we'll see if there is a reason Abe Haskins didn't do it that way in the first place.

Comment: I appreciate you debugging this! I've merged this fix into the firebasin sources. If you patch anything else, please do a PR or email me directly (abe@abehaskins.com). I don't have time to maintain Firebasin, but am always happy to take fixes.